# iOS CoreData custom subclassing of NSManagedObjecgt

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I have Controller1 with a form data entry. Then, calculations are done in a model; a segue is done to a detail controller called, let's say, Controller2. I followed subclassing NSManagedObject as usual for specifying custom methods for the calculations.

I have read other SO threads on this but none address this particular scenario.

1/ When user fills in form data & hits a button, it segues to Controller2 that shows some calculations on the data entered & passed in. So far so good. Calculations are done through functions in the model class.

2/ This Controller2 has a textfield. If there is valid text in this field, user should be able to save the data. If textfield is empty, user should not be able to save data. Ignore the UI disabling/enabling of Save button for now.

3/ If I were to follow [Custom initializer for an NSManagedObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489578/custom-initializer-for-an-nsmanagedobject) & use the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` it worked, but there's a subtle problem.

This ends up creating an empty row even when textfield in Controller2 is empty. That's because when one assigns the data to Controller2, then in order to show the calculations in Controller2 from the NSManagedObject subclass using said subclass functions, one needs to instantiate the subclass. Which basically inserts an entity in to the ManagedObjectContext. But if the textfield is empty in controller2, I'd like to show the data calculations, but not have already inserted into the managedobjectcontext until checking is done later when user taps save.

Is there a way around this issue without having to create 2 classes:

- a normal non-CoreData class with all functions with static method calls to creating instances of another class which is the actual subclass of `NSManagedObject`.
- the subclass of NSManagedObject mapping data from above class

This would be a pain since data from functions have to be shown in UI as well as stored, only the storing is done conditional to some form data being present ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init the managed object class you can pass nil for the context. Just be sure that you insert the object later when ready and don't try to rely on anything that requires the context to be set while doing your calculations (presumably you already don't as its data based).

Comment: ... and if you get to the point where the entire view controller is a form that the user can cancel, you can use child contexts (and all the attendant complexity), and save to the parent only if required.

Comment: @Wain thank you for the response - indeed calculations don't rely on context.

Comment: @stevesilva I have never used that approach but can appreciate the complexity of it so prefer not to use that. The nil context approach seems easier so will go with that for now. Thank you both !!